# A View pode conversar diretamente com o Model?

Tags: mvc

Em MVC a **View** serve para lidar com toda a interface do usuário, o **Model** serve para conter as classes que representam o sistema e suas regras de negócio e o **Controller** realiza a comunicação entre a View e o Model (algo como controlar o fluxo de dados), seguindo esta linha de raciocínio eu posso concluir que tanto como a View e o Model não conversam entre si.

Segue um pequeno exemplo em Java para contextualizar:

Classe ViewPessoaCadastro:

```
public class ViewPessoaCadastro extends JFrame {            
    public ViewPessoaCadastro() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    private void Salvar(ActionEvent evt) {//Clique
        //Salvar os dados.            
    }                       

    private void Listar(ActionEvent evt) {//Clique                        
        //Obtem todas as pessoas cadastradas e exibi para o usuario.
    }                           
}
```

Classe ControllerPessoa:

```
public class ControllerPessoa {
    Pessoa pessoa;
    
    public ControllerPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) { 
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }
    
    public void salvar() { 
        pessoa.salvar();
    }
    
    public void alterar() { 
        pessoa.alterar();
    }
    
    public List<Pessoa> listarTodas() { 
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = pessoa.listarTodas();
        return pessoas;
    }
    
    public List<String> obterErrosValidacao() { 
        List<String> errosValidacao = pessoa.validar();
        return errosValidacao;
    }
}
```

Classe Pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa {      
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Pessoa() { }

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    
    public void salvar() { 
        //Rotina para salvar no banco de dados.
    }
    
    public void alterar() { 
        //Rotina para registrar a alteração dos dados no banco de dados.
    }
    public List<Pessoa> listarTodas() {
        //Rotina para listar todas as pessoas salvar no banco de dados.
        ...            
    }
    
    public List<String> validar() { 
        //Rotina para validar a classe pessoa (Regras de negocio).
        ...
    }
    
    /*Getters e Setters*/
    public String getNome() { return nome; }

    public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

    public int getIdade() { return idade; }

    public void setIdade(int idade) { this.idade = idade; }
}
```

---

## Dúvidas

Considerando o exemplo acima em Java me surgiu a seguinte dúvida:

Onde eu preencho os atributos da classe `Pessoa`, faço isso na view criando um objeto de tipo `Pessoa` e depois passo ele no construtor da classe `ControllerPessoa` ou eu crio um método na classe `ControllerPessoa` que contenha todos os parâmetros que representam os atributos da classe `Pessoa`? Considerando a questão acima existe alguma possibilidade da View conversar diretamente com o Model?

PS:*Podem dar exemplos em outras linguagens também, mas de preferência poderia ser Java mesmo.*

Comment: normalmente é função dos `helpers` fazer essa comunicação da view com model.

Comment: @DanielOmine os helpers são uma quarta camada?

Comment: De que tecnologia estamos falando? Sei que é em Java, mas qual o *framework* MVC?

Comment: Dener, sim, é um "presentation layer". Não confundir com "service layer".

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez nenhuma tecnologia, se quiser pode citar algum framework MVC :)

Comment: @DanielOmine não sabia que havia outras camadas além das três principais.

Comment: MVC é algo mais genérico. Há diversas variações como MVVM, PM, MVP, etc. Para iniciantes, não precisa ir tão a fundo pois só vai complicar o entendimento. Você vai saber qual padrão adotar quando surgir as necessidades.

Comment: @DanielOmine o MVC pode ser usado sem esses outros padrões? Se sim, é como eu posso coletar informações da view e mandar para o model para que as informações seja persistida em algum banco de dados?

Comment: Por enquanto, esqueça esses outros padrões do comentário anterior.  Sobre a view pegar algo do banco de dados, tavez uso do GoF (padrão observer). Vide resposta do Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na definição do **Gof** (Gang of Four), a única comunicação permitida entre *Model* e *View* é utilizando o *Design Pattern Observer*.
Não há problema algum uma *view* "conversar" com um *model* desde que essa "conversa" seja em formato do padrão *Observer*, ou seja, a *view* pode apenas observar as mudanças de *model* para refletir isso para o usuário. Neste e somente neste caso, o *controller* não se envolve e o *model* e *view* podem se comunicar. Caso contrário, o *controller* deve ser invocado para comunicação entre *view* e *model*.

O que é comum de se utilizar para auxiliar nessa comunicação é o padrão **ViewHelper** que se localiza entre o *controller* e a *view*. Este padrão tem como objetivo pegar os dados da *view* e convertê-los em um objeto pré-formatado para ser enviado para o *controller*. O *controller* por sua vez, pode ter uma associação com *model* e é ele quem realiza a ação de recuperar os dados da *view* e persistir os dados em *model*.

Resumindo, não é adequado a *view* ter qualquer associação com *model*, exceto em um único caso que é quando a *view* observa alterações em *model* para refletir isso para o usuário. Para isso se utiliza o padrão *Observer*. Por fim, para ajudar o *controller* a realizar essa comunicação, utiliza-se comumente o padrão *ViewHelper*.

**Update**

Você pode interpretar essa definição e aplicar de acordo com seu entendimento. O importante é seguir os principíos do *MVC Design Pattern*.

Vou dar um exemplo: Imagine que você está desenvolvendo em um ambiente web, onde pode-se considerar um formulário HTML como a camada View, a Servlet que intercepta as requisições como a camada Controller e as classes de domínio como a camada Model.
Um código muito simples seria mais ou menos assim:

**VIEW**

```
<form method="post" action="cadastrar">
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome da pessoa"/>
<input type="text" name="idade" placeholder="Idade da pessoa"/>
<input type="text" name="frase" placeholder="Frase predileta"/>
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

*Um formulário simples que irá enviar nome, idade e uma frase predileta de uma Pessoa para um mapeamento "cadastrar".*

**VIEWHELPER**

```
public class PessoaViewHelper implements IViewHelper{
   public Entidade getView(HttpServletRequest request) {
      Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
      p.setNome(request.getParameter("nome");
      p.setIdade(request.getParameter("idade");
      p.setFrasePredileta(request.getParameter("frase");
      return p;
   }
}
```

*Neste caso, classe `Pessoa` herda `Entidade`. Logo, seu ViewHelper está extraindo os dados da `request` vinda do browser e transformando em um objeto que seja reconhecível pelo controller.*

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
   IViewHelper viewHelper;
   @Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        viewHelper = new PessoaViewHelper();
        Pessoa pessoa = viewHelper.getView(req);

        //Nesse momento, seu objeto pessoa contém os dados da view extraídas pelo view helper
       //Aqui você executa sua lógica para fazer o que quiser com o model pessoa.
       //...
       resp.getWriter().write("Pessoa cadastrada...bla bla bla");
    }
}
```

*Controller não precisa executar lógica de extração da view nem executar validações, justamente por que agora ele tem um auxiliar, que é o viewhelper.*

Esse foi um exemplo muito simplificado de como funcionaria a lógica de extração de dados utilizando o *viewhelper*.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O ViewHelper e uma quarta camada?

Comment: Você pode considerar que sim. Mas na verdade ela é uma camada auxiliar que fica situada entre a view própriamente dita e o controller. É o viewhelper que extrai os dados da view e passa para o controller formatado de uma forma que o controller possa entender e manipular o model correto.

Comment: Você pode mostrar em um pequeno exemplo como o ViewHelper extrai os dados da View e passa para o Controller?

Comment: Sim, vou fazer o exemplo aqui e editar a resposta. Só um momento.